# How to change database after altering model in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm working on this project that uses MVC. It's a simple website development project, and it uses SQL Server CE (`.sdf`) as the database.

I would like to change a couple of the underlying models, but that causes errors in the database.

I understand that I would need to change the database, and I know it's possible to create models automatically from the database.

I'm wondering if there is any way to create a database from the models. i.e. I don't mind losing all the data, but is there a way for me to change the models and then create a database that supports the existing models.

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to
Here is how you can do it. 
There are two approaches to accomplish this task.

**Method-1. (Via Package Manager Console)**

This approach for the Code First.

Open your project and go to  Package Manager Console  as follows

```
Tools--> Nuget Package Manager--> Package Manager Console
```

First Enable Migrations in your project.Type following in console.

```
enable-migrations -contexttypename yourContextName
```

This command will add a Migrations folder in your project inside this folder you will 
    see Configuration.cs inside this file you will see a seed method

```
protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
```

you can use this method to seed your database.

Now run following command in your package manager console

```
add-migration anyNameOfInitialMigrations
```

Finally To update the database simply run following command.

```
update-database
```

**Method-2.** 
  Best approach for Model First.
    Open your .edmx file.

```
Right Click--> on the model and then select "Generate Database From Model"
```

Make Sure you have proper connection strings in your web.config.